# Wireless issues with Linux Mint on Macbook Pro

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, macintosh

I installed Linux Mint 13 (Maya) on my Macbook Pro using rEFIt, and ran through the instructions [here](http://www.techlw.com/2012/06/macbook-pro-wifiwireless-drivers-for.html) to get wireless working. Now I can see a bunch of different networks, but I almost always fail to connect to them. I get constant notificaitons that my wireless is disconnected, because it keeps trying to connect, to no avail.

The wireless actually has worked one or two times. About half the time I boot into Linux Mint, I am able to connect with wireless after maybe 5 minutes of struggling. Then I promptly lose it within minutes. What are the next steps to getting this worked out?

P.S. Wireless works with OS X so I know the network and my hardware is fine.